# Problems with the php action or the "landing" page

Tags: php, html

I have a form with fields validated with JS, the form is with the

```
method = "post"
```

the information has to be stored on another server, so in the action of my form I have the "URL" of arrival to be able to insert the data of the form to the database, I have the action like this:

```
action = "http://example.com/2018/sitios/example/handle.php">
```

But at the time of landing it appears that "I can't access this website" I don't know what I'll be doing wrong, I just need help.

The error that I get is this:

> This website cannot be accessed The website http://example.com/2018/sitios/example/handle.php may be temporarily inactive or may have moved permanently to another address.
>
> ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the url in action attribute accepts only GET requests

Comment: example.com is exactly that, just an example right?  That's not the actual URL you have in your script?

Comment: do you have control of that site? Is it an API? If the answer is no to both, you probably can't access that page. Check server config and permissions